# `$_GET[1]`; payload why work in php short tag only?

Tags: php

when I try to use this payload:

```
<?= `$_GET['1']`; ?>
```

it works in php-short-tag but when I do this:

```
<?php `$_GET['1']`; ?>
```

it's not working, and give me blank page.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: This is more of a php question than a security question, and the answer is [easily located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php) if you know what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?=` is shorthand for `<?php echo`. The second one isn't echoing anything, so the page is blank.